# отправка данных в базу mysql из формы через ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

вот скрипт который проверяет данные и отправляет на сервер. проверка проходит, проблема с отправкой, не работает

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input#name, input#email, textarea#message').unbind().blur(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var val = $(this).val();

    switch (id) {

      case 'name':
        var rv_name = /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+$/;
        if (val.length > 2 && val != '' && rv_name.test(val)) {
          $(this).addClass('not_error');
          $(this).next('.error-box').text('Принято')
            .css('color', 'antiquewhite', 'font-style', 'italic', 'font-size', '12px', 'font-weight', 'bold')
            .animate({
              'paddingLeft': '10px'
            }, 400)
            .animate({
              'paddingLeft': '5px'
            }, 400);
        }


        {
          $(this).removeClass('not_error').addClass('error');
          $(this).next('.error-box').html('&bull; поле "Имя" обязательно для заполнения<br> &bull; длина имени должна составлять не менее двух символов<br> &bull; поле должно содержать только русские или латинские буквы')
            .css('color', 'black')
            .animate({
              'paddingLeft': '10px'
            }, 400)
            .animate({
              'paddingLeft': '5px'
            }, 400);
        }
        break;

      case 'email':
        var rv_email = /(\w+):\/\/([^/:]+)(:\d*)?([^# ]*)/;
        if (val.length > 2 && val != '' && rv_email.test(val)) {
          $(this).addClass('not_error');
          $(this).next('.error-box').text('Принято')
            .css('color', 'antiquewhite', 'font-style', 'italic', 'font-size', '12px', 'font-weight', 'bold')
            .animate({
              'paddingLeft': '10px'
            }, 400)
            .animate({
              'paddingLeft': '5px'
            }, 400);
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass('not_error').addClass('error');
          $(this).next('.error-box').html('&bull; Полная ссылка (припер: http://ok.ru/profile/584976889622) на Ваш профиль в соц. сети обязательна, чтоб было видно что все реально! :) )')
            .css('color', 'black')
            .animate({
              'paddingLeft': '10px'
            }, 400)
            .animate({
              'paddingLeft': '5px'
            }, 400);
        }
        break;

      case 'message':
        if (val != '' && val.length < 5000) {
          $(this).addClass('not_error');
          $(this).next('.error-box').text('Принято')
            .css('color', 'antiquewhite', 'font-style', 'italic', 'font-size', '12px', 'font-weight', 'bold')
            .animate({
              'paddingLeft': '10px'
            }, 400)
            .animate({
              'paddingLeft': '5px'
            }, 400);
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass('not_error').addClass('error');
          $(this).next('.error-box').html('&bull; Как можно отправить отзыв не написав его?')
            .css('color', 'black')
            .animate({
              'paddingLeft': '10px'
            }, 400)
            .animate({
              'paddingLeft': '5px'
            }, 400);
        }
        break;


    }

  });

  $('form#testimonials').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if ($('.not_error').length == 3) {

      $.ajax({
        url: '../../sys_files/testimonial.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: $(this).serialize(),

        beforeSend: function(xhr, textStatus) {
          $('form#testimonials :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          alert("Ошибка");
        },

        success: function(response) {
          $('form#testimonials :input').removeAttr('disabled');
          $('form#testimonials :text, textarea').val('').removeClass().next('.error-box').text('');
          alert("Спасибо за Ваш отзыв");
        }
      });
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
это сама форма 

<div class="form">
  <form method="post" action="sys_files/testimonial.php" id="testimonials">
    <input class="input-text" type="text" id="name" name="name" value="Имя *" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" />
    <div class="error-box">&nbsp;</div>
    <input class="input-text" type="text" id="email" name="email" value="Ссылка на профиль в соц. сети *" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" />
    <div class="error-box">&nbsp;</div>
    <textarea class="input-text text-area" id="message" name="message" cols="0" rows="0" placeholder="Ваш отзыв *"></textarea>
    <div class="error-box">&nbsp;</div>
    <input class="input-btn" type="submit" id="SendTestimonial" name="SendTestimonial" value="Выказаться" />
  </form>
</div>
```

а это пхп обработчик

```
if (isset($_POST['SendTestimonial'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $email = htmlspecialchars($email);
    $name = htmlspecialchars($name);
    $message = htmlspecialchars($message);

    $addTestimonials = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'testimonial'('name', 'link_soc', 'testimonial') VALUES (".$name.", ".$email.", ".$message.")");

    if (!$addTestimonials) {
        echo "Отзыв не добавлен!";
    } else {
        echo "Спасибо большое за Ваше мнение!";
    }
}
```

к базе конечно же я подключен! и это не школьная задача, помогите разобраться, спасибо!

Comment: 1. Почему `action` формы и `url` в ajax запросе не совпадают? 2. Даже если вы проверили данные на стороне пользователя, вы должны их повторно проверить на сервере! 3. Функция `htmlspecialchars()` не спасет вас от **sql-инъекции**. P.S. Если скрипт на сервере все-таки запускается, а данных нет, то ищите их в `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что нет конкретного описания ошибки.